# Play sound when receiving a web chat message

Tags: jquery

How can I add simple sound when a message arrives in a web chat session with jQuery?

I noticed that they do it on the chat at http://chat.stackoverflow.com and I want to emulate that in my own software.

Comment: @drachenstern: I had never tried it before, but I just did, so yes, it is perfect and that's what I need.

Comment: sorry, you want to emulate what you saw here... my apologies.

Comment: Open this link and hope you can find a better solution
[Play sound][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483455/play-sound-when-message-received/15498712#15498712

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) allows you to do this, and avoid Flash (with the HTML5 `<audio>` tag).

**Edit:**
As drachenstern noted in the comments, SO Chat actually uses jPlayer.  Some code from the chat page:

```
<div id="jplayer" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
  <embed name="jqjp_flash_0" id="jqjp_flash_0" src=
  "http://or.sstatic.net/chat/Jplayer.swf" width="0" height="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
  quality="high" flashvars="id=jplayer&amp;fid=jqjp_flash_0&amp;vol=80"
  allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage=
  "http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />

  <div id="jqjp_force_0" style="text-indent: -9999px;">
    0.7310569109395146
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does it degrade gracefully for non-HTML5 sites to a flash plugin?

Comment: @drachenstern - Yes, on the page: "support older browsers using a Flash Fallback"

Comment: Also, as a note, I think this is the one that this chat uses anyways, so there you go.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a [jQuery Sound plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sound) that controls a Flash element?

> This is a simple sound player, it uses flash to play the sounds, but DOES NOT provide a flash interface for any controls, everything is controlled via jQuery

```
$("#sound").sound({swf: url});
 $("#sound").load(url);
 $("#sound").play();
 $("#sound").pause();
 $("#sound").stop();
 $("#sound").volume(0-100);
```